# Merge conjoint sets in C++

Tags: c++, vector, set, intersection

Starting from a vector of vector of `unsigned int`...

```
vector<vector<unsigned short int> > matrix;
vector<unsigned short int> row;
```

I would like to merge conjoint sets (that are vectors with common elements).

For istance, as input:

```
matrix[0] = {0, 1, 2}
matrix[1] = {1, 10}
matrix[3] = {9}
matrix[4] = {2, 8}
matrix[5] = {7}
```

as output:

```
matrix[0] = {0, 1, 2, 10, 8}  // it doesn't matter the order
matrix[1] = {9}
matrix[2] = {7}
```

Which is the most efficient solution for this problem?
Best regards, Vi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce this problem to **finding all connected components** of an undirected graph. The vertices are your matrix rows, and edges are non-zero overlap. The [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html) library can compute this in `O(V+E)` complexity where `V` is the number vertices (matrix rows) and `E` the number of edges (number of overlapping rows). If you don't like the dependency on Boost, you can use any of the [available algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for computing strongly connected components.

What remains is to compute the edge-list representation of this graph, which depends on whether you are able to sort your matrix rows. If cannot sort your matrix rows, you can use [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) to detect non-zero overlap (which has `O(N * M)` complexity for 2 vectors of `N` and `M` elements). If you can sort them (in `O(N lg N)` complexity), you can use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to test for overlap (only `O(N + M)` complexity).

The output of the Boost.Graph or your algorithm is a set of connected components, and you then loop over each component and append or merge the various overlapping rows of your matrix together (using `std::copy`, or `std::merge` if you need them sorted).

Comment: I'm sorry to be annoying, but could you show me an example with code? (with boost)

Comment: @vdenotaris I think this problem is a little too large to be solved here with a full code example.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [disjoint set forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). For each set iteratively add the numbers to the set where the first number of the set belongs. After doing that simply print all the numbers in each of the sets. In fact the implementation is not that hard but the performance will be asympthotically faster than the one of the solution already proposed.